# Can you read HDF5 dataset directly into SharedMemory with Python?

Tags: python, shared-memory, hdf5, h5py, hdf

I need to share a large dataset from an HDF5 file between multiple processes and, for a set of reasons, mmap is not an option.

So I read it into a numpy array and then copy this array into shared memory, like this:

```
import h5py
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

dataset = h5py.File(args.input)['data']
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(
    name=memory_label,
    create=True,
    size=dataset.nbytes
)
shared_tracemap = np.ndarray(dataset.shape, buffer=shm.buf)
shared_tracemap[:] = dataset[:]
```

But this approach doubles the amount of required memory, because I need to use a temporary variable. Is there a way to read the dataset directly into SharedMemory?

Comment: A suggestion: check the methods of `dataset` variable. I remember there was one called `read_direct` or something like that. [h5py doc for dataset](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an observation: in your code `dataset` is an h5py dataset object, not an NumPy array. It does not load the entire dataset into memory!

As @Monday's commented, `read_direct()` reads directly from a HDF5 dataset to a NumPy array. Use it to avoid making an intermediate copy when slicing.

This is how to add it to your code. (Note, I suggest including the `dtype` keyword with your `np.ndarray()` call.)

```
shared_tracemap = np.ndarray(dataset.shape, dtype=dataset.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
dataset.read_direct(shared_tracemap)
```

You can use `source_sel=` and `dest_sel=` keywords to read a slice from the dataset. Example:

```
dataset.read_direct(shared_tracemap,source_sel=np.s_[0:100],dest_sel=np.s_[0:100])
```